# laravel backpack don't show subfields in relationship belongsToMany

Tags: laravel-backpack

I have two models Users and Roles. If I make a BelongsTo - HasMany relationship backpack shows the subfields

User(has a role_id field)

```
public function roles(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
}
```

Role

```
public function users(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

RoleCrudController

```
'label'     => 'User',
'name'      => 'users',
'type'      => 'relationship',
'entity'    => 'users',
'subfields' => [
    [
        'name'  => 'name',
        'label' => 'User name',
    ],
]
```

But I need a belongsToMany relationship, via a pivot table

User

```
public function roles(): belongsToMany
{
     return $this->belongsToMany(
            Role::class,
            'role_user_table',
            'user_id',
            'role_id'
      )->using(RoleUser::class);
}
```

Role

```
public function users(): belongsToMany
{
     return $this->belongsToMany(
            User::class,
            'role_user_table',
            'role_id',
            'user_id'
      )->using(RoleUser::class);
}
```

RoleUser model

```
class RoleUser extends Pivot
{
    use CrudTrait;
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'role_user_table';

    public $incrementing = true;

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'user_id',
        'role_id',
    ];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class, 'role_id');
    }
}
```

сrud backpack with this relationship shows the description attribute, but does not show the subfield

RoleCrudController

```
'label'     => 'User',
'name'      => 'users',
'type'      => 'relationship',
'entity'    => 'users',
'subfields' => [
    [
        'name'  => 'name', <-- empty input
        'label' => 'User name',
    ],
]
```

Comment: Have you managed to figure this out?

Comment: Nevermind, I ended up using a `custom_html` field, added script tags with an Ajax call to the Api and building dynamic fields client-side. The input fields all submits with the request object, can extract the values within `Store` and `Update` and save them manually.